# How to get css button to stay active after it has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make a nav bar where once the user clicks on the image, the image stays active.  In the following example the leaf would stay green after is is clicked.  Here is a bit of code of what Im talking about:

```
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#LinkURL">Leaf</a>

<style>
 .myButtonLink {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('http://kyleschaeffer.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/buttonleafhover.png') bottom;
    text-indent: -99999px;
 }
 .myButtonLink:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bnaegele/XHBZf/2/

```
$('.myButtonLink').click(function() {
     $(this).css('background-position', '0 0');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a class to it on click.

```
$('.myButtonLink').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

This code has an added effect of deselecting the leaf on a second click. Depending on your requirements, you might want it or not.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/stulentsev/XHBZf/1/