# Pressed <button> selector

Tags: css

I'd like to create a `button` that changes its style when it gets pressed. This is my CSS code:

```css
button {
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

button:active {
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

It is changed only when I click & hold on it. I want to make it change style after it's pressed. For example, normal state would be white, state while being clicked would be green and after click is released it would be red.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830048/how-to-get-css-button-to-stay-active-after-it-has-been-clicked

Comment: See this answer - I believe it is what you are looking for (use a checkbox and style it with CSS to look like a button) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover  --- make sure you look at the Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/4/)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can do this if you use an `<a>` tag instead of a button. I know it's not exactly what you asked for, but it might give you some other options if you cannot find a solution to this:

Borrowing from a demo from another answer here I produced this:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

a:active {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

a:target {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a id="btn" href="#btn">Demo</a>
```

Notice the use of `:target`; this will be the style applied when the element is targeted via the hash. Which also means your HTML will need to be this: `<a id="btn" href="#btn">Demo</a>` a link targeting itself. and the demo http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Awdq5/4/

Thanks to @BenjaminGruenbaum here is a *better* demo: http://jsfiddle.net/agzVt/

<sub>Also, as a footnote: this should really be done with JavaScript and applying / removing CSS classes from the element. It would be much less convoluted.</sub>

Answer (score 22):

You could use `:focus` which will remain the style as long as the user doesn't click elsewhere.

```
button:active {
    border: 2px solid green;
}

button:focus {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Should we include a little JS? Because CSS was not basically created for this job. CSS was just a style sheet to add styles to the HTML, but its pseudo classes can do something that the basic CSS can't do. For example `button:active` active is pseudo.

**Reference:**

http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/ You can learn more about pseudo here!

**Your code:**

The code that you're having the basic but helpfull. And yes `:active` will only occur once the click event is triggered.

```
button {
font-size: 18px;
border: 2px solid gray;
border-radius: 100px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

button:active {
font-size: 18px;
border: 2px solid red;
border-radius: 100px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

This is what CSS would do, what rlemon suggested is good, but that would as he suggested would require `a` tag.

**How to use CSS:**

You can use `:focus` too.  `:focus` would work once the click is made and would stay untill you click somewhere else, this was the CSS, you were trying to use CSS, so use `:focus` to make the buttons change.

**What JS would do:**

The JavaScript's jQuery library is going to help us for this code. Here is the example:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
}
```

This will make sure that the button stays red even if the click gets out. To change the focus type (to change the color of red to other) you can use this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
  // find any other button with a specific id, and change it back to white like
  $('button#red').css('border', '1px solid white');
}
```

This way, you will create a navigation menu. Which will automatically change the color of the tabs as you click on them. :)

Hope you get the answer. Good luck! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with php if the button opens a new page.

For example if the button link to a page named pagename.php as, url: www.website.com/pagename.php the button will stay red as long as you stay on that page.

I exploded the url by '/' an got  something like:

url[0] = pagename.php

```
<? $url = explode('/', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )+1,strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))); ?>


<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .btn{
     background:white;
     }
    .btn:hover,
    .btn-on{
     background:red;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="/pagename.php" class="btn <? if (url[0]='pagename.php') {echo 'btn-on';} ?>">Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

note: I didn't try this code. It might need adjustments.

Comment: Please note that the anchor <a> will have both classes when clicked or have the mouse hover and btn-on is the one saying whats up according to the cascades rules as it's echoed out after the class btn.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `:active` over `:focus` with `:hover` will help!
Try

```
button {
background:lime;
}

button:hover {
background:green;
}

button:focus {
background:gray;
}

button:active {
background:red;
}
```

**Then**:

```
<button onkeydown="alerted_of_key_pressed()" id="button" title="Test button" href="#button">Demo</button>
```

**Then**:

```
<!--JAVASCRIPT-->
<script>
function alerted_of_key_pressed() { alert("You pressed a key when hovering over this button.") }
</script>
```

```
 Sorry about that last one. :) I was just showing you a cool function! 
Wait... did I just emphasize a code block? This is cool!!!
```