# not changing color when clicking button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

i am using bootstrap to change the button color when clicked, but i think i am doing something wrong and the button is not changing it's color when i am clicking the button.

this is my button code -

```
<td>
     <a class="mylink" href="#"><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">{% trans %}Allow{% endtrans %}</button></a>
</td>
```

this is my javascript code ---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('isCliked'){
        $("#mylink").addClass('btn-success');
                $("#mylink").removeClass('btn-default');
        }
        $('#mylink').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('btn-success');
                $(this).removeClass('btn-default');
                // set the value upon clicking
                localStorage.setItem('isCliked', true)
        });
```

i need to change the button color when clicked and when the page is called again it should check whether it is activated or not.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `Button` under `a` tag?? why ??

Comment: @TusharGupta why not ?

Comment: @Hacketo: Because the specs say so.

Comment: @Abhitalks well, I don't see that in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a-changes),  see what 'phrasing content' mean

Comment: @Hacketo: [*The interactive element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.button.html#button.button-constraints) and [*Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: @Hacketo: And also vice-versa: [*The interactive element a must not appear as a descendant of the button element*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a-constraints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem is here.

```
$("#mylink")
```

This selects the element with the `id="mylink"` and not the element with the `class="mylink"`

If you want to select a class, go for this.

```
$(".mylink")
```

CSS Selectors: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `mylink` is a **class** in your code.

```
<a href="#" class="mylink">
```

But in jQuery you're using an **ID** (`$("#mylink")`). Also, `<a>` is an ascendent of   `<button>`. So correct your every bit of `$("#mylink")` to:

```
$(".mylink button")
```

That way you'll be targeting  the  `<button>` tag inside your `<a>` tag with class `.mylink`.

**Reference:** http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

With `$('#someID')` you are selecting something by it's id. But you use classes ("myLink") so you should use `$(".myLink").`

And despite that you make it more complicated than it needs to be. Maybe you want to try to do it just with css.

Here is an example which is very similar to your question:
[Pressed <button> CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463854/pressed-button-css)

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code:

1. It is jQuery, not JavaScript (it's a little bit different)
2. You are changing the `<a>` class "myLink" NOT the `<button>` class
3. You are referring to a class (`".myClassName"`) as a id (`"#myIdName"`)
4. Others things (i.e. how javascript handle the DOM element)... you should read and study a little bit more.

Anyway, I've made you a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7sd79yd/).