# Active Button Doesn't Work

Tags: html, css

I want these buttons to be and stay active when clicked on but can't get it to work, and the "currentButton" to be active by default on page load. I am able to see the style for :active when I'm clicking on either button, but it doesn't stay active after clicking.

HTML for the 2 buttons:

```
<div class="w3-center invButtons">
    <button class="w3-button currentButton">Current</button>
    <button class="w3-button pastButton">Past</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.w3-button{
    border: 2px solid #555555;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.invButtons {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    margin: 30px 10px;
}

.w3-button:hover {
    color:#000!important;
    background-color: gray!important;
}

.w3-button:active {
    color:yellow!important;
    background-color: yellow!important;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463854/pressed-button-css

Comment: do you have to use buttons? and can you use javascript?

Comment: I don't have to use buttons and I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:active` psuedo class is only applied while the button is being interacted with (i.e. "active").  Just like the `:hover` psuedo class is only applied while the mouse is hovering over the element.

If you want to apply a style to an element to signify it is the active/selected/in-use element out of a group, you need to add some sort of `.active` class to it after it is clicked and style that class.

And add that class to the button tag in the html that you want to start active.